# RecyclerView: No adapter attached

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I know that this question has been already asked, but having checked the answers, I still can't figure out the solution. This is my adapter:

```
 public static class StarredReposViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    LinearLayout starredReposLayout;
    TextView starredRepoName;

    public StarredReposViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        starredReposLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.repo_starred_item_layout);
        starredRepoName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.starredepoName);
    }
}

public StarredReposAdapter(List<GitHubstarredRepos> repos, int rowLayout, Context context) {
    this.starredRepos = repos;
    this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public StarredReposAdapter.StarredReposViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                       int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
    return new StarredReposViewHolder(view);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(StarredReposViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.starredRepoName.setText(starredRepos.get(position).getStarredName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return starredRepos.size();
}
```

And this is the method I load it in:

```
 public void loadStarredRepos (View view){

    final RecyclerView recyclerViewSt = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.starred_repos_recycler_view);
    recyclerViewSt.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    GitHubStarredRepoAPI apiService =
            ApiClient.getClient().create(GitHubStarredRepoAPI.class);

    Call<List<GitHubstarredRepos>> call = apiService.getStarredRepoName(newString);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<GitHubstarredRepos>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<GitHubstarredRepos>> call, Response<List<GitHubstarredRepos>>
                response) {

            recyclerViewSt.setAdapter(new StarredReposAdapter(response.body(), R.layout.list_item_starred_repo,
                    getApplicationContext()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<GitHubstarredRepos>> call, Throwable t) {
            // Log error here since request failed
            Log.e("Repos", t.toString());
        }

    });

}
```

The body of onResponse is entered correctly. The problem cannot be that it is on defined in the onCreate, as I have anther Recycle View, on the same screen, loaded from a different method. Thank you!

PS: The response of response.body() [image: Here]

Comment: What `response.body()` returns ?

Comment: It returns an ArrayList with n elements, each of them has name taken correctly from the API, just checked in the logs again.

Comment: Show me the response for _response.body()_

Comment: Added a picture of the logs, above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from the practice, you should have your RecyclerView#setAdapter() in mainThread in #onCreate()

`public void onCreate() { 
       recyclerViewSt.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }`

What you need to update inside the onResponse() is the dataSet that is used to feed your Adapter.

You can extract your response.body() which returns an array of object (List repos) into a global variable in your activity. Like:

`List<GitHubstarredRepos> myDatasource = new ArrayList<>();`

Then use it:

`myAdapter = new StarredReposAdapter(myDatasource, R.layout.list_item_starred_repo, getApplicationContext()));`

Next, inside the callback of network call:

`onResponse(response) {
    myDatasource.clear();
    myDatasource.addAll(response.body());
    myRecyclerview.notifyDatasetChanged();
}`

Voila, my psedocode code, not sure about the syntax ;)

Comment: Okey, I'll try this right away, but where is the first line of code written (myAdapter =...) I have access to _response_ only within the onResponse method.

Comment: There isn't a method notifyDatasetChanged() within onResponse available. there is notify() and notifyAll(). If either of the is invoked, the error says:  java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify() Do you have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Pff, needed to attach it on the adapter, not the RecyclerView :)) thanks!

Comment: My bad, I wrote that answer from my phone :p